# Linear map an isomorphism iff it maps bases to bases.

Tags: linear-algebra

Just wanted to check the following:

A linear map is an isomorphism if and only if it maps bases of the source to bases of the target?

(I think I have a proof which essentially shows that a linear map is injective if and only if it maps independent sets to independent sets and is surjective if and only if it maps spanning sets to spanning sets)

Comment: Yes that's correct

Answer (score 1):

Even better, a linear map $T:V\to W$ is an isomorphism if and only if $T$ maps *one* basis of $V$ to a basis of $W$.